# jQuery load best practice

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have a question about jQuery load best practice. Imagine the following situation:

```
$("#div").on('click', function() {
$('#result').load('test.html');
});
```

The code works fine, the load method executes, but now the loaded content can't be accessed by a jQuery plugin. I solved like this:

```
$("#div").on('click', function() {
$('#result').load('test.html', function(){
$('.element').plugin();
});
});
```

My question is simple, is there a better way to solve this situation ?

Comment: Yes. Use `$.on()`. Although I'm not really sure what "can't be accessed" means - a plugin can access it just like any other element after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you would need to target the `parent` of the element with `id="div"` ... let's say a container `<div id="wrap">` for this example. Then use `.on()` using the `parent` container as selector like:

```
$("#wrap").on("click", "#div", function() {
 $('#result').load('test.html');
});
```

then the loaded content can be accessed by your other plugin.

This format of using `.on()` actually replaced `.live()` since jQuery v1.7.x.

Eventually, you could also do

```
$("body").on("click", "#div", function() {
 $('#result').load('test.html');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it in the correct way. your code to call the plugin method will execute only after the load finishes loading to the div. So you are good to go.

Probably you can wrap all your code inside the document.ready to make sure this will be executed only after the dom finishes loading.

```
$(function(){
     $("#div").on('click', function() {
        $('#result').load('test.html', function(){
           $('.element').plugin();
         });
      });    
});
```